# Adding to multiple foreign keys at once from Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have this FAQ model which has a foreign key to Organization.

```
class Faq(BaseModel):

    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    faq_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faq_content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    faq_category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("organization", "faq_title"),)
```

[image]

From the Django Admin I can add an FAQ to an Organization. How can I make it so that I can add to all Organizations at once in the Django Admin? The goal is to have some FAQs available to all organizations, and some FAQs to just one or two organizations.

Comment: "_The goal is to have some FAQ's available to all organizations_" this implies you should be using a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) instead of a `ForeignKey`

Comment: Ok, but as I've said. Some should only be available to one organization. So I still use a ManyToManyField for that and then just select one organization?

Comment: Yes of course, A `ManyToManyField` does not mean an all to all relation ;). For a `ManyToManyField` a select tag with the `multiple` attribute is rendered by default so you can select multiple of the related objects in the same dropdown. This can be any number from 0 to the number of objects you have.